# Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{f(\frac{k}{n}) }$ exist? Why?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$ f: [0;1] \rightarrow (0; +\infty) $,
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{f(\frac{k}{n}) }$ appears to be non-existent (as the gut feeling tells me), since it's basically the sum of images of all possible rationals between 0 and 1. Even if a sequence such as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{f(\frac{1}{2^k}) }$ converges, for example, we'd still have infinitely many series such as this one added up. So, what do you think? If it does exist, can you provide the example of such a function, if not, why?

Comment: Just take any constant function to see that the sum does not converge in general.

Comment: Constant functions very clearly do not converge, but the question is if the same can be said for the most general case of a positively valued function.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous on any subinterval $(a,b)$ (and non-identically zero on this interval) then this limit is $+\infty$, which can be established by "Riemann-sum theorem"

Comment: It reminds me of a Riemann sum, so maybe it can be transformed into one?

Comment: I think if you want to create a counterexample $f$ where the limit does exist, you could focus on $\sum_{k=0}^{n!} f(k / n!)$ so that each sum includes the terms from the previous one; and at each step you can choose the new values of $f$ to be small enough that the limit exists.  Then, $\sum_{k=0}^n f(k / n) \le \sum_{k=0}^{n!} f(k / n!)$; and the values of $f$ at irrational numbers don't matter at all.

Comment: Oh, wait... except that then, for example there are infinitely many $n$ such that $f(1/2)$ does not appear in the sum; so, if $\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]} f(x)$ converges to $S$, then for those $n$, $\sum_{k=0}^n f(k/n) \le S - f(1/2)$.  So, I think the conjecture is true, but not entirely for the reason you conjectured it to be true.  While it is possible for $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]} f(x)$ to be finite (easier proof being that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable) -- in those cases, infinitely many sums miss including $f(1/2)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Could you please add an answer using your comments; you have good knowledge of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly find examples where $S(n)=\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}{f(\frac{k}{n}) }$ is bounded above for all $n$:

for example if  $f\left(\dfrac ab\right)=\dfrac1{b^3}$ where $\frac kn$ is written as $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b$ coprime integers and $b\ge 1$,

then the sum is bounded above by its supremum  of $1+ \dfrac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(3)}\approx 2.368433$ approached when $n$ is a large factorial, and bounded below by its infimum of $2$ approached  when $n$ is a large prime.

So this points a general counter example using Daniel Schepler's comments:  consider each odd prime $p$, and you can say that $$S(p!) -S(p) \ge f(\tfrac12)$$ since every term in $S(p)$ is included in $S(p!)$, though $f(\tfrac12)>0$ is not in $S(p)$ while it is in $S(p!)$.

So $S(n)$ does not have Cauchy convergence and so does not have a finite limit.

Comment: Or even just $S(2p) - S(p) \ge f(1/2)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler that is simpler (+1) and indeed you just need an odd number.